# Primitives in Object update but Array in Object doesn't

Tags: javascript

I am passing an object to a function, does that stop it from being a reference ?

I have a global POOLS structure that holds all pools. I am passing a pool into
a function with poolname[id] and then I pass that parameter to another function. Then I update values of that passed object inside of the function. Primitives work fine, but pushing to the array delMsgPool doesn't appear to alter the globally available Object, but only the local "instance".

Even though the primitives update on the global object.

#### POOLS structure

```js
export const POOLS = { [poolName] : { [id] : {delMsgPool : [], ... } }}
```

#### Function call

```js
( pool => {
  const ticket = pool.id;

  // excerpt of "nestedFunc" is below
  nestedFunc(ticket); // <= did this turn into a value? If so how did the primitives update
})(poolname[id])
```

#### Nested Function

```js
  // these update normal
  dashT.startedCoaching = Date.now();
  dashT.lockedEmojiInteractionGroups = ['selectStudent'];
  dashT.studentQTicketID = qTicket.id;

  /** @type {[{value: import('../Models/Queue_Pool.js').QPE_Opts}, {value: Message}]} */
  const [{ value: queuePoolEntry }, { value: answer }] = await Promise.allSettled([
    Queue_PoolEntry.findOne({ id: qTicket.id }),
    qTicket.coach.send(studentMessage(qTicket)),
    updateAllDashboards(),
  ]);

  
  dashT.delMsgPool.push(answer.id);
  //dashT now has the id inside of delMsgPool
  console.log(POOLS);
  // POOLS.DashTicket_Pool[dashId].delMsgPool is still [] ... the other values are on the object 
  // though
```

[image: Primitive updates, array doesn't]

Comment: **does that stop it from being a reference ?** No.

Comment: In JavaScript, values *are* references. Nothing makes copies of objects automatically.

Comment: Try `console.log(JSON.stringify(POOLS))`. You may be seeing an artifact of the way the console logs objects lazily.

Comment: @Barmar I am checking with vscodes debugger, its aligned with what the console.log in the debug console says. Also each ticket inside of pool has a reference to pool, and in that reference the `delMsgPool` is also `[]`. I know 100% that the array is not being populated, because later code references that array and it stays empty

Comment: Then it's probably related to the asynchronous code. Something down the line isn't awaiting.

Comment: @Barmar the answer is awaited properly there and I have its id. It is available in the dashT. In the globally derived pool, and in the pool reference in dashT it stays empty
(edited to show it in a picture)

Comment: What is `pool.id`? I don't see any `id` property in the object.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. It's really hard to tell how the variables correspond to the properties of the original object.

Comment: @Barmar `answer.id` (from `answer is awaited properly and I have *its* id)

Comment: What is `poolname`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220944/discussion-between-twiggeh-and-barmar).